# How do you specify a transition in the kotlinx.html DSL?

Tags: kotlinx-html

I'm building a web toy using the kotlinx DSL, and trying to do the equivalent of adding `transition: color 1s`. I expect that within a `css {}` block, I should either be setting `transition` or be setting `transitionProperty` + `transitionDuration`.

Is this right? If so, how? The `Transition()`, `TransitionProperty()` and `TransitionDuration()` constructors don't seem to take any arguments, and there don't seem to be any class properties to refer to. I wonder if maybe my IntelliJ is somehow misconfigured, because the source on github does have constructors with parameters.